# Как преобразовать картинку 32bppARGB в 8bppRGB - C++/CLI WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Добрый день. Нуждаюсь в подсказке ,как преобразовать картинку PixelFormat 32bppARGB в 8bppRGB,так как OpenCV c форматом 32bppARGB не работает, а мне необходимо загрузить туда изображение ,которое я получаю через PrimaryScreen. Оно формата 32bppARGB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355135/c-sharp-converting-32bpp-image-to-8bpp

Comment: @iluxa1810 - я как раз переводил этот ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356108/5045688).

Мой вольный перевод:

> GDI+ в общем имеет очень плохую поддержку для индексированных форматов пикселей. Нет простого способа конвертировать изображение с количеством цветов 65536 или 16 миллионов в формат с 2, 16 или 256 цветами. Цвета должны быть удалены из исходного изображения, что приводит к конверсии с потерями и очень плохому результату. Есть много алгоритмов, которые можно применить для достижения цели, но ни один из них не идеален для всех видов изображений. Это работа для графических редакторов.
>
> Есть один трюк, который я (Hans Passant) нашёл. GDI+ имеет энкодер для GIF файлов. Это графический формат, который имеет только 256 цветов. Энкодер обязан ограничить количество цветов. Он использует алгоритм сглаживания, подходящий для фотографий. У него есть склонность генерировать сетку (шум), от чего вы вряд ли будете в восторге. Используйте его так:

```
Image^ Convert(Bitmap^ oldbmp) {
    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
    oldbmp->Save(ms, ImageFormat::Gif);
    ms->Position = 0;
    return Image::FromStream(ms);
}
```

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;
using namespace System::IO;
```

Вызов метода:

```
Bitmap^ oldbmp = gcnew Bitmap("old.jpg");
Bitmap^ newbmp = (Bitmap^)Convert(oldbmp);
newbmp->Save("new.gif");
```

> Возвращаемое изображение имеет формат 8bpp с палитрой, рассчитанной энкодером. Вы можети привести изображения к `Bitmap`, если нужно. Это однозначно лучшее, что можно сделать, чтобы не заморачиваться с индексируемыми форматами. Они датируются каменным веком ЭВМ, когда память была сильно ограничена. Или используйте профессиональный графический редактор.

Comment: а в 24bppRGB ? То есть только убрать альфа - есть способ ?

Comment: @ValeryV - Во-первых, задавайте новый вопрос. Во-вторых, этот ответ конкретно про индексированные (indexed) форматы (каюсь, не разглядел сразу).